# Location Service GPS, Set High Priority

Tags: android, geolocation, location, locationmanager, android-fusedlocation

I have an Android app which uses Background Service which works in foreground mode and is sticky. This service continuously polls for GPS location every 15 minutes.

After around 1 hour of time (this is random), the service stops giving the location. We are using Fused Location Provider to fetch the location.

Is there any way to set Location OS Process on high priority?

Comment: Are you using Android M?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocationRequest` object to set the high accuracy

```
 mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest().setInterval(15000).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

and in `onConnected()` use

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mContext);
```

Comment: Hi Damanpeet can you explain more where i set these line of codes please

Comment: @humayoonn [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/) you can find a working example.. let me know if this help